# Parsing html with Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to extract some data from a search result from this website http://www.cpso.on.ca/docsearch/default.aspx

Here's a sample of the HTML code that's been .prettify()

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <a class="doctor" href="details.aspx?view=1&amp;id= 72374">
   Smith, Jane
  </a>
  (#72374)
 </td>
 <td>
  Suite 042
  <br />
  21 Jump St
  <br />
  Toronto&nbsp;ON&nbsp;&nbsp;M4C 5T2
  <br />
  Phone:&nbsp;(555) 555-5555
  <br />
  Fax:&nbsp;(555) 555-555
 </td>
 <td align="center">
 </td>
</tr>
```

Essentially every `<tr>` block has 3 `<td>` blocks.

I want the output to be

`Smith, Jane Suite 042 21 Jump St Toronto  ON  M4C 5T2`

I also have to separate entries by a new line.

I'm having problem writing the address which is stored in the 2nd `<td>` block.

I'm also writing this to a file.

Here's what I have so far... it doesn't work :p

```
for tr in soup.findAll('tr'):
    #td1 = tr.td
    td2 = tr.td.nextSibling.nextSibling 

    for a in tr.findAll('a'):
        target.write(a.string)
        target.write(" ")

    for i in range(len(td2.contents)):
        if i != None:
            target.write(td2.contents[i].string)
            target.write(" ")
    target.write("\n")
```

Comment: Your first `for` loop is missing a `:`, and the inner loop isn't indented.  Is that the actual code or a posting mistake?

Comment: Yes. my bad. Python is something I've just picked up to do some quick html parsing. I

Comment: I'm also thinking of not even looping over td and a  and just making 2 temp td values when I loop through tr.

Comment: You say, "Doesn't work".  What does it do?

Comment: It produces a list of name of Doctors separated by a new line.

Comment: The text "Suite 042 ..." is not contained in an `<a></a>`, so why do you expect your code to print it?

Comment: ^I wrote that I was having trouble with the 2nd td block. I understand that it wouldn't print, I was just offering what I had coded at the time. I'll update my question with some new code I just made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do most of what you want:

```
import os
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)

with open('output.txt', 'wb') as stream:
    for tr in soup.findAll('tr')[1:]: # [1:] skips the header
        columns = tr.findAll('td')
        line = [columns[0].a.string.strip()]
        for item in (item.strip() for item in columns[1].findAll(text=True)):
            if (item and not item.startswith('Phone:')
                and not item.startswith('Fax:')):
                line.append(item)
        stream.write(' '.join(line).encode('utf-8'))
        stream.write(os.linesep)
```

**UPDATE**

Added some code to show how to write the names and addresses to file.

Also changed the output so that names and addresses are written on one line, and phone and fax numbers are omitted.

Comment: When i changed the print methods to .write, I get a UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0'

Comment: Still didn't work. 

`http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Why can't Beautiful Soup print out the non-ASCII characters I gave it?`

^ says that it could be my Python installation or something with BeautifulSoup itself. According to that, it's BeautifulSoup >>;

Comment: @KylePDM. It's very unlikely that there's anything wrong with either Python or BeautifulSoup. What does your code for reading the html and writing the output look like?

Comment: Thanks for looking at my problem! I'll just try to remove phone/fax and put each doctor's information on oneline

Comment: If I only had the reputation to give Vote up your solution I would. For some reason nothing is being written to the output file. But I think I can tinker and fix it :D

Answer (score 1):

```
In [243]: soup.getText(' ').replace('&nbsp;', ' ').strip()
Out[243]: u'Smith, Jane (#72374)  Suite 042 21 Jump St Toronto ON  M4C 5T2 Phone: (555) 555-5555 Fax: (555) 555-555'
```

To get exactly what you want:

```
In [246]: address = soup.getText(' ').replace('&nbsp;', ' ').strip()
In [247]: import re
In [248]: address = re.sub(r' Phone.*$', '', address)
In [249]: address = address.replace('  ', ' ')
In [250]: address = re.sub(r' \(.*?\)', '', address)
In [251]: print address
Smith, Jane Suite 042 21 Jump St Toronto ON M4C 5T2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(your_html, 
               convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)

for tr in soup.findAll('tr'):
   td = tr.findAll('td')

   target.write(td[0].a.string)
   target.write(' ')

   target.write(' '.join(text.strip() for text in td[1].findAll(text = True)[:-2]))) #finds all text subnodes, except 2 last ones (phone number), and joins them with ' ' separator
   target.write("\n")
```

Comment: This just gives me the names separated by a new line